# Python and sqlite3 data structure to store table name and columns for multiple reuse

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using python sqlite3 api to create a database.
In all examples I saw on the documentation table names and colum names are hardcoded inside queries..but this could be a potential problem if I re-use the same table multiple times (ie, creating table, inserting records into table, reading data from table, alter table and so on...) because In case of table modification I need to change the hardcoded names in multiple places and this is not a good programming practice..
How can I solve this problem? 
I thought creating a class with just constructor method in order to store all this string names..and use it inside the class that will operation on database..but as I'm not an expert python programmer I would like to share my thoughts...

```
class TableA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.table_name = 'tableA'
        self.name_col1 = 'first_column' 
        self.type_col1='INTEGER'
        self.name_col2 = 'second_column' 
        self.type.col2 = 'TEXT'
        self.name_col3 = 'third_column' 
        self.type_col3 = 'BLOB'
```

and then inside the DB classe

```
table_A = TableA() 

def insert_table(self): 
    conn = sqlite3.connect(self._db_name) 
    query = 'INSERT INTO ' + table_A.table_name + .....  <SNIP> 
    conn.execute(query)
```

Is this a proper way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to start using classes to provide an abstraction layer for your database tables, you might as well start using an ORM. Some examples are [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and [SQLObject](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLpePlwr3OAhVEkJQKHYa3DUIQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sqlobject.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNHkK2hl0vwT6BKzo62_YCTNLoI-0g&sig2=eYX0ekics0PS-qauqrXYQw&bvm=bv.129422649,d.dGo), both of which are extremely popular.

Here's a taste of SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = declarative_base()

class TableA(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tableA'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_column = Column(Integer)
    second_column = Column(String)
    # etc...

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine

session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

ta = TableA(first_column=123, second_column='Hi there')
session.add(ta)
session.commit()
```

Of course you would choose semantic names for the table and columns, but you can see that declaring a table is something along the lines of what you were proposing in your question, i.e. using a class. Inserting records is simplified by creating instances of that class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's proper but I can tell you that it's not conventional.

If you really want to structure tables as classes, you could consider an object relational mapper like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). Otherwise, the way you're going about it, how do you know how many column variables you have? What about storing a list of 2-item lists? Or a list of dictionaries?

```
self.column_list = []
self.column_list.append({'name':'first','type':'integer'})
```

The way you're doing it sounds pretty novel. Check out their code and see how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like to use libraries and frameworks without proper reason. So, if I'd such reason, so will write a thinking wrapper around `sqlite`.

```
class Column(object):
    def __init__(self, col_name="FOO", col_type="INTEGER"):
        # standard initialization
```

And then table class that encapsulates operations with database

```
class Table(object):
    def __init__(self, list_of_columns, cursor):
        #initialization
    #create-update-delete commands
```

In table class you can  encapsulate all operations with the database you want.